# iMacros Element specified by TAG command was not found

Tags: firefox, runtime-error, imacros

I'm getting firefox imacro plugin error code -921. How can I fix this ?

**iMacro Script**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:balance-change<SP>fail CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

*OR*

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:image ATTR=CLASS:balance-change<SP>fail CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

**Firefox iMacro Error**

```
RuntimeError: element INPUT specified by CLASS:balance-change<SP>fail
was not found, line: 1 (Error code: -921)
```

**My target html tag**

```
<div id="game-result" class="balance-change fail">
    <span id="result-text">
    LOST
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't have images in your target html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:balance-change<SP>fail CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

Put this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:balance-change<SP>fail CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```